# Updating an entity with a List

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

**Controller**

```
...
// field will represent a previously filled up field
Field field = this.unitOfWork.FieldRepository.GetByID( fieldID );

// But I want to remove some of these things called
// field attributes from its array, so I empty it out, 
// and refill the list
field.FieldAttributes = null;
field.FieldAttributes = new List<FieldAttribute>();

foreach (var fieldAttributeGroup in fieldAttributes)
{
    foreach (var fieldAttributeID in fieldAttributeGroup.Attributes)
    {
        if (fieldAttributeID != "false" && fieldAttributeID != null)
        {
            // dbFieldAttribute is from the database
            FieldAttribute dbFieldAttribute = this.unitOfWork.FieldAttributeRepository.GetByID(Convert.ToInt32(fieldAttributeID));
            // I fill the new field up
            field.FieldAttributes.Add(dbFieldAttribute);

        }

      }
  }

// I send the field to the repository:
this.unitOfWork.FieldRepository.Update( field );
```

**Repository**

```
public void Update( Field field )
{
    Field dbEntity = context.Fields.Find( field.FieldID );    
    dbEntity.FieldAttributes = field.FieldAttributes;
    context.SaveChanges();
```

**The problem:**

Existing field attribute relationships that were attached to a field in the database remain attached even though I have set that attribute equal to the new set of field attributes.

**The question:**

Do I have to remove entries that existed... explicitly or is there a way to make Entity framework handle all of the relationship modifications.. obviously some existing field attribute relationships are not explicitly remove at this point.